# Best way to include JavaScript in a JSP taglib jar

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags, custom-tag

I'm building a taglib with a few custom tags. Some of these require a bit of JavaScript to work properly. What would be the best way to add the JavaScript so that it's included in the taglib jar?

The most obvious approach to me would be to put it into the custom tags' `doStartTag()` method like this `pageContext.getOut().print("<script>my js</script>");`, which I don't like for 2 reasons: It looks absolutely horrible and it gets added every time the tag gets used on a page.

I'm looking for a solution that lets me keep the JavaScript in a separate .js file that rests somewhere in the taglib jar and gets included only once per page whenever a custom tag is used.